# Error in JavaScript when implementing input field shadow

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to implement a shadow into an input field. This is the JavaScript code that I am using:

```
<!-- input field shadow  -->
var placeholder = "test field"
$("input").on({
    focus: function() {
        if (this.value == placeholder) {
            $(this).val("").removeClass("shadow");
        }
    },
    blur: function() {
        if (this.value == "") {
            $(this).val(placeholder).addClass("shadow");
        }
    }
}).trigger("blur");​
```

When I run the code in Firefox I get this error message:

> illegal character }).trigger("blur");

Is there a bug into the code? How I can fix it?

Comment: Works perfectly fine >> http://jsfiddle.net/skram/ZcdZ7/1/ << in FF for me.

Comment: I would like to ask you how I can turn this code into JavaScript function. I'm new to JavaScript. And How I can call this function into JSF code.

Comment: Are you sure you're using straight quotes (" ") and not curly quotes (“ ”)?

Comment: it's the ; and the spaces behind it, probably copied from word or somewhere else, read my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is something wrong with the ;
maybe you pasted it from word or whatever but I see the error in FF

Delete the ; and any spaces after it then type it again, it will get rid of the error

Edit: I think the spaces or tabs behind the ; but do the above the error will disappear

Edit: to use it in a function you simply wrap it with a function

```
var addListener = function(){
    // your code here
};
```

then to call it, on document ready most likely

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    addListener();
});
```

Comment: Yes! the empty space after ; was the problem

Comment: I would like to ask you how I can change the color of the text which is displayed as usual text right now. I want to display it in grey color. Now the color is black.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are using `jQuery 1.6.4`, which will not work.

Try using `jQuery 1.7.1` and above version